# python beautifulsoup4 parsing google finance data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to using beautifulsoup and scraping in general so I'm trying to get my feet wet so to speak.

I'd like to get the first row of information for the Dow Jones Industrial Average from here:
http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=INDEXDJX%3A.DJI&ei=ZN_2UqD9NOTt6wHYrAE

While I can read the data and print(soup) outputs everything,  I can't seem to get down far enough. How would I select the  rows that I save into table? How about the first  rows?

Thank you so much for your help!

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import sys
import os
import time
import csv
import errno

DJIA_URL = "http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=INDEXDJX%3A.DJI&ei=ZN_2UqD9NOTt6wHYrAE"

def downloadData(queryString):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(queryString) as url:
        encoding = url.headers.get_content_charset()
        result = url.read().decode(encoding)
    return result

raw_html = downloadData(DJIA_URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_html)

#print(soup)

table = soup.findAll("table", {"class":"gf-table historical_price"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the second `tr` table row then:

```
prices = soup.find('table', class_='historical_price')
rows = prices.find_all('tr')
print rows[1]
```

or, to list all rows with prices info, skip the one with any `th` elements:

```
for row in rows:
    if row.th: continue
```

or use that first header as a source for dictionary keys:

```
keys = [th.text.strip() for th in rows[0].find_all('th')]
for row in rows[1:]:
    data = {key: td.text.strip() for key, td in zip(keys, row.find_all('td'))}
    print data
```

which produces:

```
{u'Volume': u'105,782,495', u'High': u'15,798.51', u'Low': u'15,625.53', u'Date': u'Feb 7, 2014', u'Close': u'15,794.08', u'Open': u'15,630.64'}
{u'Volume': u'106,979,691', u'High': u'15,632.09', u'Low': u'15,443.00', u'Date': u'Feb 6, 2014', u'Close': u'15,628.53', u'Open': u'15,443.83'}
{u'Volume': u'105,125,894', u'High': u'15,478.21', u'Low': u'15,340.69', u'Date': u'Feb 5, 2014', u'Close': u'15,440.23', u'Open': u'15,443.00'}
{u'Volume': u'124,106,548', u'High': u'15,481.85', u'Low': u'15,356.62', u'Date': u'Feb 4, 2014', u'Close': u'15,445.24', u'Open': u'15,372.93'}
```

etc.

Comment: Hi, when should I use .find and when .find_all?

Comment: `.find()` finds the *first* match only or returns `None`, `.find_all()` returns a list of 0 or more matches.

Comment: Great. This really helps. Is row.th specific to beautifulsoup? never seen that before.

Comment: Yes, it is. Any attribute that BeautifulSoup doesn't recognize is translated into a `.find()` call. `row.th` is thus translated to `row.find('th')`.