# python comprehension from two list or zip

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have two lists:

```
labels = chunks[0].split("\n")
print(labels)
['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']

day0 = chunks[1].split("\n")
print(day0)
['Feb 7, 2014', '15,630.64', '15,798.51', '15,625.53', '15,794.08', '105,782,495']
```

I want to combine them to have:
['Date':'Feb 7, 2014', ...., 'Volume':'105,782,495']

I've tried using both zip and a comprehension but can't seem to get it to work. I can easily do this with a double for loop but I'm trying to learn the pythonesque way of doing it.

For instance, this doesn't seem to work:

```
zipped = zip(labels, day0)
print(zipped)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What you say you want isn't valid Python syntax. Do you want a dictionary?

Comment: My [BeautifulSoup answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21654495/python-beautifulsoup4-parsing-google-finance-data/21654539#21654539) to your previous question showed you how to do just this.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Yep. but I was trying to break it down directly into it's components. Plus copying your code was giving me something a bit different. I figured I'd make it on exactly this rather than combining both things. Thanks though for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
zipped = dict(zip(labels, day0))
```

or

```
zipped = {lab:day for lab,day in zip(labels, day0)}
```

**Edit:** It looks like labels will change rarely if ever; depending on how days and stocks you want to store, it might be more efficient to use a namedtuple as follows:

```
from collections import namedtuple

labels = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
StockDay = namedtuple('StockDay', [s.lower() for s in labels])

day0 = ['Feb 7, 2014', '15,630.64', '15,798.51', '15,625.53', '15,794.08', '105,782,495']
item = StockDay(*day0)

print(item)
```

which results in

```
StockDay(date='Feb 7, 2014', open='15,630.64', high='15,798.51', low='15,625.53', close='15,794.08', volume='105,782,495')
```

then fields can be accessed as

```
item.date        # => 'Feb 7, 2014'
```

How important is this?

```
import sys

print(sys.getsizeof(zipped))    # => 524 bytes
print(sys.getsizeof(item))      # => 52 bytes
```

... the namedtuple uses just under a tenth as much memory as the dict.

Answer (score 0):

Although Huge's answer above is fancy enough, I want to add two points.

1. `['Date':'Feb 7, 2014', ...., 'Volume':'105,782,495']` is invalid syntax for python,

   `[` and `]` indicate that it is a list, while `:` indicates that it might be a dictionary.

   It seems like `{'Date':'Feb 7, 2014', ...., 'Volume':'105,782,495'}` would be better.
2. zip(labels, day0) will just return a list of tuples, as stated in python documentation (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

   So, with

   ```
   zipped= zip (labels, day0)
   ```

   zipped will be something like

   ```
   [('Date', 'Feb 7, 2014'),
   ('Open', '15,630.64'),
   ('High', '15,798.51'),
   ('Low', '15,625.53'),
   ('Close', '15,794.08'),
   ('Volume', '105,782,495')]
   ```